# JAVAX RS WS Client Exceotion NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, javax

We are migrating CXF version 2.7.7 to 3.1.8 and facing the belows issue.
And also updated javax.rs.ws 2.0-m10 to 2.0.1

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/client/ClientException
```

If we are using the same  javax.rs.ws 2.0-m10, facing the below issue

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/NoContentException
```

Anyone have the solution, what could be the right version of Javax-rs-ws version which contains both the classes?

Comment: Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

From the CXF 3.1.x [migration guide](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/31-migration-guide.html)

> Support for using JAX-WS 2.1 based API jars has been removed.  Java 7
>   (now required) includes JAX-WS 2.2 so this should not be an issue.